# A word for someone who repairs bikes

Tags: single-word-requests

I want a  single word for someone whose job is to repair bikes

Comment: It's a bicycle mechanic or bicycle repairman.  There ain't no "single word".

Comment: or bicycle repairer.

Comment: Depending on how specific the problem to be repaired is, you might be able to call the person a _derailleurist_.

Comment: @SvenYargs - Which I would take to mean a terrorist out to derail trains.

Comment: @HotLicks: And a French terrorist at that.

Comment: You could ask for a second opinion on bicycles.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Googling "a person who repairs bicycle" Google then completed the rest with "*is called what?"* that led me immediately to the answer. I didn't have to open a page, nothing.  I really don't see why this question should get any upvotes. Any native speaker would know the answer to this. The OP didn't even explain why they wanted a single word.

Comment: @SvenYargs *Derailleurist* doesn't even exist in French, and the word *derailleur* refers only to the gear system, invented in 1927, of de-railing the chain from one sprocket to another.

Comment: @WS2: At least I didn't suggest _gearondist_.

Answer (score 2):

A ***[bicycle mechanic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_mechanic)*** :

> - is a mechanic who can perform a wide range of repairs on bicycles. (Wikipedia)

[image]A bicycle mechanic at a  bike shop.

Comment: or ***bike repairman*** or ***bicycle repairman***

Comment: Many thanks broo it seems that there is no single word for that

Comment: [bicycle repairman](//www.youtube.com/watch?v=U01xasUtlvw)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want a single word, you might go with the compound ***biketech***. But it isn't standard.

***Tech*** is short for *technician*.

Comment: or *bikemech* ?

Comment: .......or bikerep?

Comment: @ermanen - "mech", in bicycle terminology, is usually taken to mean "mechanism".

Comment: Or perhaps a _bixfix_?

Answer (score 0):

Bike mechanic though its two words.

Comment: Hi, Rolen, another answer that was flagged as low-quality. Please do not answer a question like this. Your post received three **recommend deletion** in the review. Just a heads-up.